# How do I add a loop into this macro to repeat 'x' amount of times

Tags: excel, vba, loops

I am trying to combine multiple macros into one. How do I add a loop so that it repeats itself 'x' amount of times, with 'x' being the values of Sheet3!A1, and then it executes the print preview function?

This is the VBA code I have so far. I cant seem to get the loop to work correctly. Im trying to work out what I need to add to *"I CANT WORK OUT WHAT TO PUT HERE"*

```
Sub Calculate()
    ' Macro to copy data to a new row, run it a specified number of times, and print output.
    
    ' Turn off screen updating.
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    ' Declarations.
    Dim copySheet As Worksheet
    Dim pasteSheet As Worksheet
    Dim targetRange As Range
    Dim loopCount As Long
    Dim i As Long
    Dim printSheet As Worksheet
    
     ' Set variables.
    Set copySheet = Worksheets("Sheet5")
    Set pasteSheet = Worksheets("Sheet6")
    Set printSheet = Worksheets("Sheet6")

    ' Unlock pasteSheet to allow editing.
    pasteSheet.Unprotect Password:="password"
    
    ' Set targetRange as the last cell in column C with a value.
    Set targetRange = pasteSheet.Cells(pasteSheet.Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
    
    ' Set targetRange as the first cell in column C without conditional formatting
    ' under the last cell in column C with no value.
    Do Until targetRange.FormatConditions.Count = 0
        Set targetRange = targetRange.Offset(1, 0)
    Loop
    
    ' Copy range C22:M22.
    copySheet.Range("C22:M22").Copy
    
    ' Paste the copied range into targetRange.
    targetRange.PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
    
    ' Lock pasteSheet to prevent further editing.
    pasteSheet.Protect Password:="password"
    
    ' Get the loop count from Sheet3!A1
    loopCount = Sheets("Sheet3").Range("A1").Value
    
    ' Loop from 1 to the specified loop count
    For i = 1 To loopCount

   '          # **"I CANT WORK OUT WHAT TO PUT HERE"**

    Next i
    
    ' Unprotect and unhide printSheet.
    printSheet.Visible = xlSheetVisible
    printSheet.Unprotect Password:="password"
    
    ' Open print preview for the specified range.
    printSheet.Range("B1:N46").PrintPreview
    
    ' Hide and protect printSheet again.
    printSheet.Protect Password:="password"
    printSheet.Visible = xlSheetHidden
    
    ' Turn off the cut-copy mode.
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    
    ' Turn on screen updating.
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Ive tried copying this as the task I want to repeat in to *"I CANT WORK OUT WHAT TO PUT HERE"*

```
' Set variables.
    Set copySheet = Worksheets("Sheet5")
    Set pasteSheet = Worksheets("Sheet6")
    
    ' Unlock pasteSheet to allow editing.
    pasteSheet.Unprotect Password:="password"
    
    ' Set targetRange as the last cell in column C with a value.
    Set targetRange = pasteSheet.Cells(pasteSheet.Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
    
    ' Set targetRange as the first cell in column C without conditional formatting
    ' under the last cell in column C with no value.
    Do Until targetRange.FormatConditions.Count = 0
        Set targetRange = targetRange.Offset(1, 0)
    Loop
    
    ' Copy range C22:M22.
    copySheet.Range("C22:M22").Copy
    
    ' Paste the copied range into targetRange.
    targetRange.PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
    
    ' Lock pasteSheet to prevent further editing.
    pasteSheet.Protect Password:="password"
```

Comment: Please explain why `Set targetRange...` isn't enough and you need `Do Until...`. Are there formulas in `C22:M22` that should update (how?) on each iteration i.e. why are you copying everything and not just values? Could you share an example where the range is to be copied multiple times (e.g. 3 times) with exact target sheet addresses?

Comment: Hi, I am coming back to an old project which I got some help with from another user in regards to the `Set targetRange` and `Do Until` . Please see [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72675836/vba-help-copy-paste-in-same-sheet-in-next-available-row). If I am being honest I do not fully understand how to use VBA, but you are right the `Do Until` is no longer needed as I have made changes to the spreadsheet. There are formulas in `C22:M22` which update based on the values of cells in the row above as each row is copied and pasted. I hope that answers your questions? @VBasic2008

Comment: What about `printSheet`? It isn't specified anywhere. Is it sheet `Sheet3`?

Comment: Sorry, that was an over sight. I was playing around with it at the time I posted the question but I have added it in. `printSheet`  is `Sheet6`, i.e. `pasteSheet`. They were both separate as they were originally separate macros which I decided to combine. I have now removed everything relating to `printSheet` and renamed it as `pasteSheet` to avoid confusion. I can post the whole VBA code now that I've finished it. @VBasic2008

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve my question. I was trying to adapt on old macro and mis-understanding the loop function.

I have removed the following from the above code:

```
' Set targetRange as the last cell in column C with a value.
Set targetRange = pasteSheet.Cells(pasteSheet.Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)

' Set targetRange as the first cell in column C without conditional formatting
' under the last cell in column C with no value.
Do Until targetRange.FormatConditions.Count = 0
    Set targetRange = targetRange.Offset(1, 0)
Loop

' Copy range C22:M22.
copySheet.Range("C22:M22").Copy

' Paste the copied range into targetRange.
targetRange.PasteSpecial xlPasteAll

' Lock pasteSheet to prevent further editing.
pasteSheet.Protect Password:="password"
```

AND I have amended the loop to be:

```
' Get the loop count from Sheet3!A1
loopCount = Sheets("Sheet3").Range("A1").Value

' Loop from 1 to the specified loop count
For i = 1 To loopCount

    ' Set targetRange as the last cell in column C with a value.
    Set targetRange = pasteSheet.Cells(pasteSheet.Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)

    ' Copy range C22:M22.
    copySheet.Range("C22:M22").Copy

    ' Paste the copied range into targetRange.
    targetRange.PasteSpecial xlPasteAll

Next i
```

The above now removes redundant code and allows my desired function to run "X" amount of times with "X" being the value of Sheet3A1. Note as per comments I forgot to define printSheet which I have now amended in my original question.